# finding sigma algebra of random variable

Tags: probability

I find learning probability theory by applying measure theory and sigma algebra quite challenging.
I am trying to figure out this task:
Lets say we have function $X:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $X:=I_{(-\infty,3)}-I_{[3,\infty)}$.

So $\sigma(X)$ is:

$\{(-\infty,3),[3,\infty),\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}$

Correct?

Comment: Yes, correct!..